# Replace empty date values with a matching value from the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
CS.ID,
CS.Import_Date,
CS.Secondary_Date
FROM
Center_Summary CS
ORDER BY CS.Import_Date
```

Which returns values like this:

[image: img1]

And I want to replace these "empty" values which are pulling as `01/01/1900` with the value of `05/01/2019`. In this case, it's because the `ID` and `Import_Date` match, so the `Secondary_Date` should match as well. I've thought to use `REPLACE()` (`REPLACE(CS.Secondary_Date, '01/01/1900', ???`), but I'm not sure how to write logic to pull in a matching value from the column `Secondary_Date` based on `ID` and `Import_Date` - what function should I be looking to use here?

How it's currently pulling (the dates in red I want to replace):

[image: img1]

What my expected result is:

[image: img2]

Comment: The date `01/01/1900` isn't an "empty" value. The only value that is *close* to representing empty would be a zero length, or "empty", string in SQL Server, in my opinion. Some do also say that `NULL` means empty, but i tend to look at this as it being "unknown" (which is what a `NULL` is truly defined as).

Comment: Gotcha - so it truly is a NULL value then.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `UPDATE` with a `WHERE`?

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET SecondaryDate = ImportDate
WHERE SecondaryDate = '19000101';
```

Comment: Well I actually need to set SecondaryDate to *another value* in the secondary date column where ID and Import_Date match the other row - does that make sense?

Comment: I think we need more examples here, @dwirony, and *not* images.

Comment: I do not know how to explain without pictures and my SQL knowledge is too poor to converse fluently - I added my expected results pictures above.

Answer (score 0):

"Empty" values are best represented by `NULL`.  I would recommend converting them to `NULL`:

```
nullif(secondary_date, '1900-01-01')
```

If you really want another value, then you can use `coalesce()` or a `case` expression:

```
coalesce(nullif(secondary_date, '1900-01-01'), '2019-05-01')
```

However, I'm not generally a fan of such magic values in the code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with best practices - do you think it's too much to try and force change these null values to something else?

Comment: @dwirony . . . The suggestion is that the `'1900-01-01'` dates be stored as `NULL` -- if the meaning is that the date does not apply.  There are some cases where such dates are appropriate.  But, for instance, if it were a first purchase date and there are no purchases, then `NULL` is appropriate.

Comment: I don't think I explained my issue fully - please see my the before/after pictures I've added above to show what my expected outcome is.